# Getting Parameters out of Query String doesn't work...Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, parameters

I've got to code a webapplication for a university project.
It's something like a calender using JSP, Javascript, Java, JQuery and SQL.
So I've come pretty far, but i've got a Problem with my Query Strings.
I am trying to give the Id of the clicked Cell on to another Page, which is supposed to look in the Database for an Entry with that id. I am Passing this Id through a QueryString, but can't get it out.
I've tried everything. Every little Piece of Code, which was supposed to get the Parameters out.
That's my latest try:

```
    var i = location.search.split('i=')[1];
```

to test if the parameter has been cut out, i've tried this, which isn't working...

```
    var x = document.getElementById("vname");
    x.setAttribute("value",i);
```

vname ist the id of an input field of the form on that site.
Thanks for the help :)
EDIT: My ID isn't just Integer it's something like this "fr21" for friday 21:00.

I've literally tried everything u recommended, but it's not working. If i use firebug on firefox it says: "ReferenceError: functionxyz is not defined" although it is...
Don't know what to do.

Comment: If you log the value of `i` in the console, what do you get ?

Comment: Setting the `value` of an `<input>` DOM element node should be just `x.value = i;`.

Comment: How is query string set ?

Comment: (at)Ilya: don't know how to log :(.... 
(at)Pointy: I've tried that aswell, doesn't work either
(at)guest271314: it's "site.jsp?i="+ident" where ident is the id of the clicked cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Using an approach like `split('i=')` is not very robust. Better use regex and filter for the specific query string value like

```
<script>
  var matches = location.href.match(/&?i=(\w+)&?/);

  if (matches !== null)
  {
    var id = matches[1];

    alert(id);
  }
</script>
```

This way you have the advantage of supporting multiple query string parameters. So when a query string like `abc=d&i=123&g=h` is used, the script will return `123`.

**Edit**

`/&?i=(\w+)&?/` means

`/` begin regular expression

`&?` match optional & character

`i=` i=

`(` start capture group, to read value later with matches[1]

`\w` match all characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _

`)` close capture group

`&?` match optional & character

`/` end regular expression

Comment: don't really know what u did in the brackets there with (/i=(\w+&/)